# Implement network bridge as userspace program?

Tags: networking, bridge, lxc

I am looking to do some packet filtering/address rewriting for packets which are coming from and going to a lxc container.

After some basic research, I figured the best way to do this is to assign a bridge network adapter to the container and have this bridge do the filtering. However, I did not find a way to implement a bridge in a userspace program (only trough the brctl command line tool), so that leads me to my questions:

1. How do I implement a network bridge with filtering in a userspace program? Can anyone point me in the correct direction?
2. Is there a better way to implement this filtering? I am looking to be able to rewrite destination addresses and drop packets basic on dynamic rules.

Please note that I am looking to implement most of it by myself and not rely (too much) on a prebuilt tool.

Comment: Why not implementing rules centrally for all the containers? There is an associated cost into copying packets to userland.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Each container has its own rules which are not necessarily the same for all. Is there some way to implement this behavior as a kernel module?

Comment: when I was using Xen I was using openvswitch, no idea if it applies to your situation. http://openvswitch.org

Comment: Sadly, I do not think that openvswitch is applicable in this situation.

Comment: Why can't `iptables` work for you? (You could "mark" packets by interface, and then use per-marker rule sets.)

Comment: Since you're bridging instead of routing `ebtables` would be a better fit.  it should be able to do what you want, though.

Comment: While ebtables and iptables would work for filtering, how can I use these to rewrite packets? I am looking to replace source/destination ip & macs in the Ethernet and IP header as well as in arp packets.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem.
I thing that this is a suitable solution https://github.com/afett/ubridge